# selenium test on ubuntu 16.04 with chromedriver

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, testng, selenium-chromedriver

i'm in UBUNTU 16.04

when i run this test :

```
sudo java -jar SeleniumTest.jar Driver Chrome Import Accounts.xml BaseUrl https://URL
```

output:

```
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.core.CoreManager main
INFO: Detected OS is : Linux
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.core.CoreManager main
INFO: Loading App Config Data
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.core.CoreManager main
INFO: App Configuration loaded Successfully
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.core.CoreManager main
INFO: Starting Test Automation ...
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.core.CoreManager main
INFO: Running All Tests
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.core.CoreManager main
INFO: Starting Test Cases ...
[TestNG] Running:
  /opt/old/VIP2/testresources/Login.xml

Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.tests.Login.LoginSuite BeforeSuiteMethod
SEVERE: Chrome driver path is either unreadable or unassigned. Please configure your AppConfig.xml
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.tests.Login.Login TestInvalidUserLogin
INFO: Starting TestInvalidUserLogin
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.tests.Login.LoginSuite AfterMethod
SEVERE: Test Case : Login.TestInvalidUserLogin()[pri:0, instance:com.company.vip.tests.Login.Login@17579e0f] Failed
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.tests.Login.Login TestValidUserLogin
INFO: Starting TestValidUserLogin
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.ilerra.vip.tests.Login.LoginSuite AfterMethod
SEVERE: Test Case : Login.TestValidUserLogin()[pri:0, instance:com.company.vip.tests.Login.Login@17579e0f] Failed
Dec 15, 2017 3:46:22 AM com.company.vip.tests.Login.LoginSuite AfterMethod
SEVERE: Test Case : SignUp.TestUserSignUp()[pri:0, instance:com.company.vip.tests.Login.SignUp@34cd072c] Failed

===============================================
LoginSuite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Running:
  /opt/old/VIP2/TestNG.xml


===============================================
allSuites
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Xvfb stopping
Finished: SUCCESS
```

the content of Appconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppConfig>
    <Environment>Staging</Environment>
    <ChromePath>/usr/local/bin/chromedriver</ChromePath>
    <ChromeProfile>/home/usr/.config/google-chrome/Default/</ChromeProfile>
    <ChromeIsHeadless>1</ChromeIsHeadless>
    <ImportParamsFrom>App</ImportParamsFrom>
</AppConfig>
```

~

Comment: Quick guess: `Appconfig.xml` has bad syntax or chromedriver is not in the specified dir: `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

Comment: @Würgspaß i get chromedriver from " which chromedriver "

Comment: what is the output of `ls -al /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7931056 Dec  9 21:44 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver @Würgspaß

Comment: ok, looks fine to me. But telling from the log messages there is something wrong with the configuration: `Chrome driver path is either unreadable or unassigned. Please configure your AppConfig.xml` Looks like `com.company.vip.core.CoreManager` is processing that file and has problems with the path. So you should investigate what CoreManager expects and what it actually reads. Seems to be third-party code so I cannot help you on that. Or is there even another `Appconfig.xml` file which has a different config?

Comment: SEVERE: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c),platform=Linux 4.4.0-103-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.10 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'vadv-selenium', ip: '172.16.50.140', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-103-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Comment: Check the chrome installation. Is it installed properly on your machine? Can you open the browser manually using the profile `/home/usr/.config/google-chrome/Default/`? If so, which version. Maybe a version conflict with chromedriver. Apart from that there seems to be headless X-Server `Xvfb` running. Could be an issue, as well.

Comment: @Würgspaß thanks for your speed response, i have one google-chrome in my machine and i can open it, xvfb is related to headless mood in Jenkins, this test triggered by Jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many of times tries and troubleshooting i found that:

1- you should run test with normal user (something related to chrome if you start it with root it will fail)
2- you have to have a x permission on chromedriver
3- you must pass all parameter on Appconfig.xml file like full pass to chromedriver and chrome profile